# How can I read the value of a cell directly into a cell reference?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets, I want to read a cell containing the string 'e' into a formula which uses the 'e' as the horizontal component of a cell reference, eg 'e12'.

Hopefully clearer example:

- a1 contains 'e'
- a2 needs to contain 'e2'
- then a2:a10 can contain 'eX' where X is 2 to 10.

I'm aware of the INDIRECT method, but I can't see how to use that to populate a2:a10 without a corresponding column of cells all containing 'e', one for each aX.

Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree.

I've got a table with list of names on the x axis and dates of meetings on the y axis. In each table element we have some string value to represent if they attended the meeting - eg "y" for attended the meeting "n" for did not, "a" for apologised for abscence in advance.

I also have a list, corresponding to the names on the x axis, of attendance, eg person1 has been to 60% of meetings. The trouble is that for every new meeting I insert a new column closest to the names list, and move all the other meetings one cell to the right. This means that for every new meeting, I have to update the formula with a new cell reference.

Before inserting a new meeting date, the formula looks roughly like DOSOMETHING(b2:y2). I then insert a column to the left of the b column. Google sheets cleverly updates the formula so to be DOSOMETHING(c2:z2), even though I really want the range to be b2:z2. I have tried DOSOMETHING($b2:y2), but inserting the column still causes this problem.

Thank you

Comment: This is a classic XY problem.  https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @MattKing you maybe right - I've updated with the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging! sometimes people resist. POsting up the solution now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
=DOSOMETHING(B2:Y2)
```

use this:

```
=DOSOMETHING(OFFSET($A2,0,1,1,99999))
```

the offset reference won't get messed up by the insertion of a column since it referrences column B by OFFSETing from column A.   99999 is just an arbitrarily large number that means "all the way to the right of the sheet.

you can [read about offset here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

try like this in row 2:

```
=INDIRECT(A1&ROW()&":"&A1&10)
```